# Memory Efficient Nearest Neighbour Algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pytorch

I have 10,00,000 agents, each associated with `(x,y)` coordinates. I am trying to find agents close to each other (`radius=1.5`). I tried to implement this using PyTorch:

```
X = torch.DoubleTensor(1000000,2).uniform_(0,10000)
torch.cdist(X,X,p=2)
```

However, with this the session crashes. I am running this on google colab. The same happened when I tried constructing the graph using, `radius_neighbors_graph` of scikit-learn package. It would be of great help if someone suggested a memory efficient way to implement the same.

Comment: Take a look at [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss)

Comment: I tried this as well, it takes well over an hour to find 10-nearest neighbours of each agent.

Comment: Can you tell something about the range of coordinates? Are the agents randomly distributed or clustered? If the world is small, you could sort the agents into buckets (rectangles of 1.5 x 1.5), then for each agent you would only have to look into 4 buckets for possible neighbors. If the world is large and the agents thinly distributed, I would choose one coordinate, e.g. x, and have all agents sorted into a tree (or other structure), which allows to quickly return all elements within an interval. Then for each neighboring agent within the interval you can check the real distance with x and y.

Comment: @Shai when I used FAISS, I face an issue. The distance between an agent i and itself is returned non-zero. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Sebastian The layout is 5Km*2Km and the agents are randomly distributed. Since I evaluate the impact of density on the outcome, there are no guarantees about the spread of agents being thin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three solutions,
Solution 1

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(3000000, 2).cuda()
y = x

# Turn our Tensors into KeOps symbolic variables:
from pykeops.torch import LazyTensor
x_i = LazyTensor( x[:,None,:] ) 
y_j = LazyTensor( y[None,:,:] )  

# We can now perform large-scale computations, without memory overflows:
D_ij = ((x_i - y_j)**2).sum(dim=2)  
D_ij.argKmin(20,dim=1)
```

Solution 2

```
M = 3000000
import numpy as np
from pykeops.numpy import LazyTensor as LazyTensor_np
x = np.random.rand(M, 2)
y = x
x_i = LazyTensor_np(
    x[:, None, :]
)  # (M, 1, 2) KeOps LazyTensor, wrapped around the numpy array x
y_j = LazyTensor_np(
    y[None, :, :]
)  # (1, N, 2) KeOps LazyTensor, wrapped around the numpy array y

D_ij = ((x_i - y_j) ** 2).sum(-1)  # **Symbolic** (M, N) matrix of squared distances
s_i = D_ij.argKmin(20,dim=1).ravel()  # genuine (M,) array of integer indices
```

Solution 3

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
M = 3000000
x = np.random.rand(M, 2)
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=20, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(x)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(x)
```

Although the execution time of all the three solutions is the same, a minute, the memory requirements are approximately 2GB, 1GB and 1.3GB, respectively. It would be great to hear ideas to lower the execution time.

Comment: 1. In the question, the aim is only to find nearest neighbours within a close radius (1.5). Calculating n nearest neighbours with any distance is unnecessarily slow and memory intensive. 2. Some of the calculations can be switched to integer arithmetic in a first step and then more accurately calculated afterwards. 3. See my solution in the question comments with 1.5x1.5 square buckets. This would probably need less than 50 MB (or even less with a compact data structure) and run below 1s on CPU or (with some optimizations) in some ms on GPU.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that you'll be able to compute a 1M*1M matrix in its entirety without thinking it through very carefully. You probably want something along the lines of [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). Once you've constructed a tree, you can pass the coordinates of an agent to the [`query`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html) method to get its neighbors within a certain radius. To get all the neighbors at once, you can come compute something like [`sparse_distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.sparse_distance_matrix.html) of the tree with itself at an appropriate threshold.

Alternatively, you can look into any number of efficient clustering algorithms.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Although generating a KD-tree takes very little time and memory, either querying it or generating a `sparse_distance_matrix` for as many agents is extremely memory intensive.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without any fancy libraries:

```
def batch_nn(X, Y, bs):
    nns = torch.zeros(len(X))
    for i in range(0, len(X), bs):
        batch_x = X[i:i+bs]
        dists = torch.cdist(batch_x, Y)
        nns[i:i+bs] = torch.argmin(dists, axis=1)
    return nns
```

Then run `batch_nn(X, X, 10)`.

This takes about a minute on my laptop, with the `X` you mention.
But it doesn't crash.
It's pretty easy to extend to finding more than the nearest neighbour as well. Just use `torch.argpartition` or `torch.topk` instead of `torch.argmin`.